# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_GLKMatrix3Identity", referenced from:

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I try to import google maps SDK and i add all the library like explained on the google maps site. Please help me! :)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_GLKMatrix3Identity", referenced from:
  gmscore::vector::GLLineGroup::SetTransform(gmscore::math::Matrix4f const&, gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::vector::Camera> const&) in GoogleMaps(GLLineGroup.o)
  gmscore::vector::GLAlphaOnlyTextureShaderProgram::GLAlphaOnlyTextureShaderProgram(bool) in GoogleMaps(GLBasicShaderState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(unsigned int) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(unsigned int) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureUnit) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureUnit, bool, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::Filter, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::Filter) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  ...
  gmscore::vector::GLLineGroup::SetTransform(gmscore::math::Matrix4f const&, gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::vector::Camera> const&) in GoogleMaps(GLLineGroup.o)
  gmscore::vector::GLAlphaOnlyTextureShaderProgram::GLAlphaOnlyTextureShaderProgram(bool) in GoogleMaps(GLBasicShaderState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(unsigned int) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(unsigned int) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureUnit) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureUnit, bool, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::Filter, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::Filter) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  ...
  gmscore::vector::GLLineGroup::SetTransform(gmscore::math::Matrix4f const&, gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::vector::Camera> const&) in GoogleMaps(GLLineGroup.o)
  gmscore::vector::GLAlphaOnlyTextureShaderProgram::GLAlphaOnlyTextureShaderProgram(bool) in GoogleMaps(GLBasicShaderState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(unsigned int) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(unsigned int) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureUnit) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureUnit, bool, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::Filter, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::Filter) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  ...
  gmscore::vector::GLLineGroup::SetTransform(gmscore::math::Matrix4f const&, gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::vector::Camera> const&) in GoogleMaps(GLLineGroup.o)
  gmscore::vector::GLAlphaOnlyTextureShaderProgram::GLAlphaOnlyTextureShaderProgram(bool) in GoogleMaps(GLBasicShaderState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(unsigned int) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(unsigned int) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureUnit) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureUnit, bool, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::Filter, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::Filter) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  ...
"_GLKMatrix4Identity", referenced from:
  -[GMSTilesEntityProvider updateAndTransformTile:camera:renderer:behavior:] in GoogleMaps(GMSTilesEntityProvider.o)
  -[GMSGLVectorTile applyTransform:camera:] in GoogleMaps(GMSGLVectorTile.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::PointsBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSPointsEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::StickerBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSStickersEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::BubbleBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSBubbleEntityProvider.o)
  gmscore::streetview::Panorama::Panorama(int, int, int, int, int, int) in GoogleMaps(Panorama.o)
  gmscore::vector::UpdateMyLocationBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GLMyLocation.o)
  ...
  -[GMSTilesEntityProvider updateAndTransformTile:camera:renderer:behavior:] in GoogleMaps(GMSTilesEntityProvider.o)
  -[GMSGLVectorTile applyTransform:camera:] in GoogleMaps(GMSGLVectorTile.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::PointsBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSPointsEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::StickerBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSStickersEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::BubbleBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSBubbleEntityProvider.o)
  gmscore::streetview::Panorama::Panorama(int, int, int, int, int, int) in GoogleMaps(Panorama.o)
  gmscore::vector::UpdateMyLocationBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GLMyLocation.o)
  ...
  -[GMSTilesEntityProvider updateAndTransformTile:camera:renderer:behavior:] in GoogleMaps(GMSTilesEntityProvider.o)
  -[GMSGLVectorTile applyTransform:camera:] in GoogleMaps(GMSGLVectorTile.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::PointsBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSPointsEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::StickerBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSStickersEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::BubbleBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSBubbleEntityProvider.o)
  gmscore::streetview::Panorama::Panorama(int, int, int, int, int, int) in GoogleMaps(Panorama.o)
  gmscore::vector::UpdateMyLocationBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GLMyLocation.o)
  ...
  -[GMSTilesEntityProvider updateAndTransformTile:camera:renderer:behavior:] in GoogleMaps(GMSTilesEntityProvider.o)
  -[GMSGLVectorTile applyTransform:camera:] in GoogleMaps(GMSGLVectorTile.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::PointsBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSPointsEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::StickerBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSStickersEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::BubbleBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSBubbleEntityProvider.o)
  gmscore::streetview::Panorama::Panorama(int, int, int, int, int, int) in GoogleMaps(Panorama.o)
  gmscore::vector::UpdateMyLocationBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GLMyLocation.o)
  ...
  -[GMSTilesEntityProvider updateAndTransformTile:camera:renderer:behavior:] in GoogleMaps(GMSTilesEntityProvider.o)
  -[GMSGLVectorTile applyTransform:camera:] in GoogleMaps(GMSGLVectorTile.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::PointsBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSPointsEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::StickerBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSStickersEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::BubbleBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSBubbleEntityProvider.o)
  gmscore::streetview::Panorama::Panorama(int, int, int, int, int, int) in GoogleMaps(Panorama.o)
  gmscore::vector::UpdateMyLocationBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GLMyLocation.o)
  ...
  -[GMSTilesEntityProvider updateAndTransformTile:camera:renderer:behavior:] in GoogleMaps(GMSTilesEntityProvider.o)
  -[GMSGLVectorTile applyTransform:camera:] in GoogleMaps(GMSGLVectorTile.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::PointsBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSPointsEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::StickerBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSStickersEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::BubbleBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSBubbleEntityProvider.o)
  gmscore::streetview::Panorama::Panorama(int, int, int, int, int, int) in GoogleMaps(Panorama.o)
  gmscore::vector::UpdateMyLocationBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GLMyLocation.o)
  ...
  -[GMSTilesEntityProvider updateAndTransformTile:camera:renderer:behavior:] in GoogleMaps(GMSTilesEntityProvider.o)
  -[GMSGLVectorTile applyTransform:camera:] in GoogleMaps(GMSGLVectorTile.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::PointsBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSPointsEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::StickerBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSStickersEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::BubbleBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSBubbleEntityProvider.o)
  gmscore::streetview::Panorama::Panorama(int, int, int, int, int, int) in GoogleMaps(Panorama.o)
  gmscore::vector::UpdateMyLocationBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GLMyLocation.o)
  ...
  ...
"_GLKMatrix4Invert", referenced from:
  gmscore::streetview::Camera::Unproject(gmscore::math::Vector2f const&, bool*) in GoogleMaps(Camera-B046EE312980DB98.o)
  gmscore::vector::Camera::UpdateInternals() in GoogleMaps(Camera-3E3856CABC8A9C74.o)
  gmscore::renderer::Camera3D::SetTransform(gmscore::math::Matrix4f const&) in GoogleMaps(Camera3D.o)
  gmscore::renderer::Camera3D::Transform() in GoogleMaps(Camera3D.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GLKView", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSEntityRendererView in GoogleMaps(GMSEntityRendererView.o)
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLKView", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GMSEntityRendererView in GoogleMaps(GMSEntityRendererView.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 29):

Hopefully you've solved this by now.  The issue you were running into is that you don't have `GLKit.framework` linked in your build phases.

You should check out the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start) page for the full list of setup instructions, but the relevant step is below.

> Open the Build Phases tab, and within Link Binary with Libraries, add the following frameworks:
>
> - AVFoundation.framework
> - CoreData.framework
> - CoreLocation.framework
> - CoreText.framework
> - GLKit.framework
> - ImageIO.framework
> - libc++.dylib
> - libicucore.dylib
> - libz.dylib
> - OpenGLES.framework
> - QuartzCore.framework
> - SystemConfiguration.framework

Answer (score 1):

Above Frameworks Plus

I noticed the following changes when I upgraded an app that was using the older Google maps SDK that had been installed manually:

Need to link to CoreBluetooth.framework and Accelerate.framework in Build Phases -> Link Bundle with Libraries.
The -all_load flag under "Other Linker Flags" will cause "duplicate symbol" errors. (Use -ObjC instead.)
If you use the CocoaPods method of installation (per their current instructions), it should take of the required frameworks but it'll still get messed up by -all_load.